# What is the default logs storage time in AD domain controller server?

Tags: active-directory, windows-domain

I do not have this with me to check, as I am not OS administrator. I suppose there is some default time set in Active Directory (AD) for logs storage. I am particularly interested in logs for user logging in/out storage. I would need to inspect these logs, as some AD users were deleted, but I have to find out the last time when they actually logged in into the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Default Tombstone Lifetime Settings (days):**

- Windows 2000 or Windows Server 2003 RTM: 60
- Server 2003 SP1: 180
- Server 2003 R2: 60 or 180
- Server 2003 SP2, Server 2003 R2 SP2, and later:180
- Windows Server 2008 and higher 180

**Determining actual system's Tombstone Lifetime Setting:**

```
dsquery * "cn=directory service,cn=windows nt,cn=services,cn=configuration,dc=<FQDN>" -scope base -attr tombstonelifetime
```

**Getting deleted objects:**

```
Ldifde -u -x -f <FileName.txt>
```

<sub>`-u` Use Unicode format
 
`-x` Include deleted objects (tombstones)</sub>

To find deleted users:

- in the `<FileName.txt>` search for `\0ADEL` string or `CN=Deleted Objects`.
- or use GUI: use `ldp.exe` and look for `CN=Deleted Objects`.

**Getting UserName and timestamp of NOT deleted users:**

```
  dsquery * -limit 0 -filter "&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=Person)" -attr sAMAccountName lastlogontimestamp
```

If more data is needed, use `-attr *`.

To convert received timestamp to date use this:

```
w32tm /ntte 130722669980039000
```

Output:

```
151299 09:16:38.0039000 - 31.03.2015 12:16:38 (local time)
```

Comment: Would it dig into logs so that **deleted** users would also be searched? Because when the user is simply blocked (disabled), then you can find a lastLogonTimestamp in users properties.

Comment: Also, it does not answer the original question, what is the default time of storage of logs for user logging in/out in AD Domain Controller server.

Comment: Thanks. What do switches `-u` and `-x` do? I don't find them in [Ldifde description by MS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731033.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @ZygD see Update -u = Unicode, -x = Include deleted objects (tombstones)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will accept it after my edits are approved :) One [additional question](http://superuser.com/questions/900995/is-it-possible-to-get-the-date-of-a-users-last-login-to-ad-if-the-user-was-dele) remains. Maybe you could help on that too.